# how to access element id from JSON in selenium webdriver java

Tags: java, json, selenium-webdriver

I am new to Java and Selenium. Please help me out.

Here is JSON data from web.

```
desk: {id: "11", table_layout_id: "1", name: "14",…}
```

In java, I wrote

```
 String str = "{ \"id\":11,\"name\":\"14\"}";
 JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(str);
 int id= obj.getInt("id");
driver.findElement(By.id("id")).click();
```

What I want to do is , 
after driver found the element which is id=11, it will be clicked.

But the error is org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException. 
This element is under "canvas". When I inspect element in Chrome, it shows only canvas id under 'Element' tab but shows JSON under 'Network' tab. To be honest, I do not know what does it mean by that but you, expert might need this.

Comment: is there an element with id=11? Is it visible? Is it under frame / iframe? Please check.

Comment: Element with id=11 present.This is not under frame/ iframe but under canvas. Is it the same?

Comment: When I inspect the element using chrome it shows only canvas id. when I check "Network" tab, shows JSON data of each element under canvas.

Comment: If you are able to get the id from JSON then the issue is in selenium code. In browser press F12 and try `document.getElementById('11')` in browser itself. I think id should be a `String`.

Comment: @Braj . I tried it in browser console. document.getElementById('11') returns null. That's why I am getting NoSuchElement error, but why it's in JSON? I'm confused .

Comment: Then it's clear that there is something wrong with HTML itself. Make sure element with that id exists. Look at view source.